# Why did Vader run away when Death Star was destroyed in the Battle of Yavin?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

In the Battle of Yavin, when Death Star was destroyed, Vader simply ran away. He was close to rebel base. Why didn't he simply land there to crush their throats?

I don't think rebels could stand a chance against a single Sith as even *The ability to destroy a planet is insignificant next to the power of the Force*. Force Telekinesis, Mind Control, Lightsaber, Instinct and non-force based battle experience could have certainly dominated the situation and he could easily crush the throats of rebel leaders.

Comment: Vader is **not** (contrary to what he claims in front of his subordinates) undefeatable. Just a few days/hours/however much time passed before, Obi-Wan had warned him, that he (Obi) would become even more powerful than Vader could imagine, and then the guy just went *puff*. Then some random rebel blows up a multi-trillion credits battle station. I would say Vader was understandably cautious.

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty convincing. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to popular (well, Vader's) belief, a Sith warrior is not immortal. Even though Vader is powerful and well armored, a frontal assault on a Rebel base would be little more than suicide.

**Here we can see a half-dozen troopers making short work of a Jedi Knight**

[image]

There's also the fact that Vader needs to report back to the Emperor on what happened as well as planning his next move against the person in the X-Wing

> Darth Vader regained control of his damaged TIE fighter. As he headed
>   for the nearest Imperial outpost, he was not preoccupied about how he
>   would explain the loss of the Death Star to the Emperor. Tarkin had
>   been responsible for the space station and its vulnerabilities, and
>   the Rebels had been more cunning than anyone had anticipated. There
>   was really nothing more to say.
>
> But there were plenty of other things to think about. Before Vader had
>   been knocked out of the trench, he’d recognized the Corellian
>   freighter as the same ship that had delivered Ben Kenobi to the Death
>   Star, reportedly from Tatooine. Vader wondered why Kenobi had been on
>   Tatooine, and how long he’d been there. Then Vader thought of the last
>   X-wing pilot in the trench. He was so strong with the Force.
>
> Vader wouldn’t rest until he learned the truth. - <sub><sup>[Star Wars: A New Hope - Junior Novelization](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

Comment: The Jedi got killed in a surprise attack. In the same movie, you can see the performance of Yoda and Obi-Wan against Clone troopers near Jedi Temple.

Comment: Also, I didn't say anything about frontal assault.

Comment: They manage to kill a half-dozen each. In the next scene we see thousands of Rebel soldiers.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 im miss understanding how vader can do anything but a frontal assult on the rebel base, they will clearly see his ship landing unless he lands miles away, and if thats the case will his suit even last long enough for him to walk miles and miles to a rebel stronghold?

Comment: I told you I am not talking about frontal assault. If there were x soldiers, he could turn x/2 against other x/2.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 - Although there's some evidence that the Sith can control minds, that doesn't seem to stretch to creating meatpuppet soldiers in sufficient quantities to prevent being immediately slaughtered by their comrades.

Comment: Clearly Darth Vader's mental and mind control abilities did not match Kimball Kinnison's or Nadrek of Palain Seven's.  Otherwise the Rebels would have been doomed once Vader approached within mental range of their base.  Thus the Lensmen seem more powerful than Jedi.

Comment: @M.A.Golding - Oh, very much so. If memory serves, those that were trained in 'lens use' could control entire fleets and planets and focus on millions of tasks simultaneously. No Jedi could do that.